# magento 2 - modify db_schema.xml field length

Tags: magento2.3

I want to change the length of action_operator field to 50 character in catalogrule_product table

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="action_operator" nullable="true" length="10" default="to_fixed"
                comment="Action Operator"/>
```

how to override the db_schema.xml
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change that Field length from Custom module.

**Create `db_schema.xml` at your module and add below code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="catalogrule_product" resource="default" >
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="action_operator" nullable="true" length="50" default="to_fixed"
                comment="Action Operator"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**And your module should depend on Magento_CatalogRule**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="{VendorName_ModuleName}">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogRule"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: I guess, length should be 50 according to the question

Comment: thanks.. for notify. Typo mistake